# Why does conditional branching in ASM 6502 have limit of 128 bytes

Tags: assembly, branch, 6502

What are the hardware reasons why a routine must be within 128 or -127 bytes of the issued branching instruction?

Comment: Simple: the offset is encoded using 8 bit signed number.

Comment: To get around this limitation, reverse the sense of the conditional jump so that it skips around a jump instruction to a location that's more than 127 bytes away. Some assemblers have a conditional branch macro that does this, but I don't know if any of the 6502 assemblers have that type of macro.

Answer (score 11):

The hardware reasons are two-fold:

- first, the 6502 is an 8-bit processor, which means a single byte can hold
  unsigned values from 0 to 255, or if bit 7 is used to indicate sign (two's complement) then -128
  to +127.
- second, Chuck Peddle designed the branch instruction as a two-byte operation - the first byte represents the branch condition (opcode) and the second
  a signed offset value (operand) to be added to the Program Counter [PC] if the      condition is true.

As is now apparent, the use of a single signed offset byte as the branch operand means the maximum 'jump' range that a `BRx` instruction can accommodate is either 128 locations back from the current PC, or 127 locations ahead.

This limitation can be cumbersome to overcome in cases where you need to *branch* (as opposed to *jump*, see below) further than the range allows; however, practice and experience in 6502 assembly programming techniques and a deep understanding of the flow and organisation of your code will often permit artful design that avoids the need to branch over larger distances.

The CPU architecture more than compensates for the range limit by having `BRx` be an incredibly fast instruction - only 2 cycles if the branch is not taken, and just one more cycle if it is (i.e. 2 cycles to read the opcode and operand and set up the compare mask in an internal register, and then just one more to add the operand to PC if the condition is true).

The `JMP` instruction, by comparison, allows program flow to jump anywhere in the 16-bit address range as it uses a two-byte address operand - but exhibits a flat 3-cycle cost and is unconditional. Careful construction of a jump table or self-modifying code using `JMP` and indexed by a branch allows the programmer to capitalise on the speed and conditionality of `BRx`  and only incur the 'far jump' cost when the condition is true.

Comment: Overcoming this limitation can be as simple as turning e.g. `BEQ label` to `BNE 3; JMP label` if `label` wouldn't fit into the signed 8-bit range.

Answer (score 5):

This is because conditional branch statements are only 2 bytes long, with the first byte being the opcode of the instruction and the second byte being a signed (two's complement) value that marks the distance to the address to branch to if the condition is true. (I believe the value is DestinationAddress - AddressImmediatelyFollowingBranchStatement). With two's complement and only one byte available, the distance to the destination address is limited to the following range: [-128, +127].

In short, it's because the designers of the 6502 provided only a single signed byte in two's complement as the parameter for the conditional branch statements.